# How to add permission limits on a discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord Bot set up but at the moment anyone can run the cleanup command which deletes messages but i only want people on the server with admin to be able to run it (if anyone could also show me how to delete one message as well that would be great, its a comment in the cleanup command), my code at the moment is:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # print message content
    print(message.content)
    # if the message came from the bot ignore it
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # if the message starts with "!repeat" then say the message in chat
    if message.content.startswith("!repeat"):
        sentmessage = message.content.replace("!repeat", "")
        await message.channel.send(sentmessage)

    if "hello" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

    if message.content.startswith("!cleanup"):
        num2c = 0
        num2c = int(message.content.replace("!cleanup", ""))+1
        print(num2c)
        await message.channel.purge(limit=num2c)
        num2c = num2c-1
        cleanmessage = str("Cleared  "+str(num2c)+" Messages.")
        await message.channel.send(cleanmessage)
        t.sleep(2)
        #needs to delete the message again afterwards
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
if not message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
    return await message.channel.send("You do not have permission to run this command!")
```

However, I'd highly recommend using the [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) extension which will handle this for you much more easily. Also, it appears that you are using `time.sleep()`. This is blocking and will not work with your asynchronous code, it will cause the bot to essentially "freeze", and not respond to anything else. Instead you should use `asyncio.sleep()`, which is non-blocking. To delete a message that you've sent after a certain amount of time, you can just pass `delete_after=number_of_seconds` to `send()`.

Comment: Thanks, can you guide me on this commands extension and how do I pass the '''delete_after''', I'm sorry I'm new and just learning?

Comment: you pass `delete_after` just as a keyword argument after your content. Here's a guide to using commands: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: await message.channel.send(cleanmessage).delete_after(2) - like that?

Comment: no, `await message.channel.send(cleanmessage, delete_after=2)`